# How to deploy STATUS TRANSITIONS under Service Appointment Life Cycle from one sandbox to another sandbox/production?

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

I am trying to find the metadata/data through which I can deploy STATUS TRANSITIONS under Service Appointment Life Cycle? is there any way via which I can migrate it or will I have to replicate it manually in other org? This is what I want to migrate:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to deploy status transitions through metadata. You'll need to add a post deployment to add manually.

Alternatively you can create a script to do this but I would recommend against this as it typically over complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce does not suggest to add the transitions using script with FSL Global API's.
These API's are to be used only in test classes.
Post Deployment steps is the only way we can add the transitions.